# Program do not write array to file

Tags: c

I have problem on Ubuntu to write into a file. I want to create file with size of 4MB so I will write 1024 blocks of size 4096 bytes. Program create a file on Desktop, but when I open it, its empty with size 0 bytes. File can be open, write returns value -1. errno says Invalid argument.

Code:

```
float timedifference_msec(struct timeval t0, struct timeval t1)
{
    return (t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) * 1000.0f + (t1.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec) / 1000.0f;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct timeval t0, t1;
    float elapsed;
    struct timespec start1, end1;
    char c_array [4096];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    int fdw = open("/home/user/Desktop/xxxy.txt", O_CREAT |O_WRONLY |O_DIRECT, 0644);

    for(i=0; i<4096; i++){
        c_array[i] = '0';
    }

    for(j=0; j<1024; j++){
        gettimeofday(&t0, 0);
        unsigned long start =
            std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
            (std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();

        write(fdw, c_array, 4096);
        fsync(fdw);
        gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
        unsigned long end =
            std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
            (std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
        elapsed = timedifference_msec(t0, t1);
        printf("%d - Elapsed time: %f : %f\n", j, elapsed, end-start);
    }

    close(fdw);

    return 0;
}
```

//method with O_DIRECT

```
void *buf;
posix_memalign(&buf, 4096, 4096);

int fdw = open("/home/user/Desktop/xx1.txt", O_CREAT |O_WRONLY| O_TRUNC|O_DIRECT, S_IRWXU);     
for(i=0; i<4096; i++){
    c_array[i] = '9';
} 

memcpy(buf, c_array, sizeof(c_array)); 

for(i=0; i<512; i++){
    gettimeofday(&t0, 0);     
    write(fdw, buf, 4096);
    fsync(fdw);   
    gettimeofday(&t1, 0);    
    elapsed = timedifference_msec(t0, t1);    
    printf("%3d - Elapsed time: %f milliseconds.\n", i, elapsed);     
} 

close(fdw);
free(buf);
```

Comment: Please add a check if `open` is successful and then report back here.

Comment: You're not checking your `write()` call for any errors - you're just assuming it works.

Comment: Why don't you use [C++ ostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) ?

Comment: `fclose` on a file descriptor isn't going to end well... Use `close`instead.

Comment: Are you writing C or C++? It's confusing. and yes, use fstreams !

Comment: Did you check `write` return? it should match the number of bytes you write.

Comment: file can open, but return value of write is -1

Comment: using C but epoch timer was here for checking right value of timer

Comment: @Majority if `write` returns -1, [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) will contain an error number which will tell you why `write` has failed.

Comment: it says invalid argument

Comment: "*file can open*" from what do you conclude this?

Comment: @alk
`if (fdw != -1) printf("file opened");`

Comment: @Jabberwocky Isn't that literally what `fclose` is for?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [`fclose`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fclose/) != [`close`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/close).

Comment: @Jabberwocky Ah yes, a `FILE*`, right.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so you say the `write` call fails with errno of "Invalid argument", i.e. `EINVAL`. In the posted code you don't actually observe that, but for the sake of argument let's say you are actually running a program which is identical other than checking errno.

[The manpage for `write`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) clearly says:

> **EINVAL**
>   `fd` is attached to an object which is unsuitable for writing; or the file was opened with the `O_DIRECT` flag, and either the address specified in `buf`, the value specified in `count`, or the file offset is not suitably aligned.

Don't use `O_DIRECT` unless you know what you're doing and why. Remove it. And read the documentation!

Comment: Is there any other solution how to open file with O_DIRECT and write to file? I need O_DIRECT flag for minimalize cache effects.

Comment: @Majority read [this](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open) and specially the `O_DIRECT` related stuff and/or google `O_DIRECT`.

Comment: @Majority Why do you think that you need to minimize cache effects?

Comment: I need to measure delay between CPU and disk.

Comment: So really this question is about how to use `O_DIRECT` correctly for that scenario.

Comment: I found one example, but result with it was really strange. [example](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/writing-files-using-o_direct-in-c-792203/)

Comment: @Majority Notice in particular the phrase on that post that says "there isn't a good reason to". And you didn't tell us what "really strange" means.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit time of writing block was strange. result of first 24 blocks: [image](https://i.imgur.com/aH55gWG.png), added code to question.